# What is the Vatican's position on ISIS?

Tags: catholicism

What is the Vatican's position on ISIS?

Specifically,  if a Catholic independently sought out the leader of ISIS and shot a bullet between his eyes,  would he/she be exalted (like an arcangel) or condemned as a sinner?

Comment: Position on something and condoning assassination I think are two different things. +1 anyway.

Comment: I think the question is fine. I'm sorry you're being downvoted without comment.

Comment: I think it would be best if you focused on the first question. It's excessively unlikely that the hypothetical in your second paragraph has been explicitly addressed by the CC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vatican recently supports the use of military force against ISIS, [as noted in this article.](http://time.com/3745462/vatican-isis-syria-iraq-middle-east/)

On that same note, per the example of your post, such a thing (be the person bad or not) would be murder. As such, the Vatican view on such a thing falls under the Fifth Commandment - "Thou shall not kill." Particularly, since you specify an independent, [section 2265](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c2a5.htm).

EDIT: To justify my answer, I'll also provide some Hebrew.

In the case of killing in the Ten Commandments (Exodus 20:1-17) we are given "רצח" (retzach) which translates *"to break, to dash to pieces" as well as "to slay, kill, murder"* (Strong's Concordance H7523). This is brought up again in Deuteronomy 5:4-21 reiteration of the Ten Commandments.

All cases of the 10 Commandments, simply put, are "Thou shall **not kill**. Simply put, no exceptions. According to the Priestly Code of the Book of Numbers, killing anyone outside the context of war with a weapon, or in unarmed combat, is considered "retzach". It should be noted that the Bible never uses "retzach" in connection with war.

There are a few instances where killing another is justified in Scripture - such as in *legitimate* warfare, capital punishment and *legitimate* self defense. However, Jesus Christ taught us:

> You have heard that it was said, 'An eye for an eye, and a tooth for a tooth.' But I tell you, do not resist an evil person. If someone strikes you on the right cheek, turn to him the other also. (Matt. 5:38-39)
>
> Love your enemies, do good to those who hate you, bless those who curse you, pray for those who mistreat you. (Matt. 5:43-48, Luke 6:27-28)
>
> Put your sword back in its place...for all who draw the sword will die by the sword. (Matt. 26:52)
>
> Blessed are the peacemakers, for they shall be called sons of God. (Matt. 5:9)

The above seem to indicate pacifism. With these taken into account, in the context of your question, an independent Catholic going out to kill the leader of ISIS would be viewed as a murderer - because s/he was neither defending themselves or fighting in war, legitimately. Nor would such a person be carrying out a capital punishment.

Comment: The commandment is **not** "do not kill".

Comment: The commandment is do not murder, but the hypothetical question described murder.

Comment: @curiousdannii the fifth commandment is very clearly, in plain English, "thou shall not kill". There is really no way around it. Even though it does specify justifications for self defense, warfare, capital punishment, etc - I stated that for the example the Asker gave in his question "Specifically, if a Catholic independently sought out the leader of ISIS and shot a bullet between his eyes" would be seen as a murderer at least per the Catechism.

Comment: @Jesse That is a wrong translation, and I don't think there's any serious argument to say that it shouldn't be translated 'murder' instead. See [Is “kill” a valid translation for Exodus 20:13](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/77/2757)

Comment: @curiousdannii see my updates made prior to me seeing this. The word used in Exodus 20:13 does, in fact, translate to "kill" among other things. So the translation would not be false. Even to translate it simply as "murder" - you have to know for a fact what was and was not legal at that time - but we cannot, since the commandment was not expounded upon until later on in the OT. That said, within the scope of the question, the answer would remain correct. Even "murder" as we understand it today, the initial question would fall under "unlawful".

Comment: Isn't "murder" _defined_ as unlawful/unjustified killing? If the rest of the law enumerates (some of which begins right after the 10 commandments in Exodus 21-23—including some about killing) instances of justified killing, then the commandment isn't talking about all forms of killing—it's talking about murder.

Comment: @mojo The fact remains - a random, independent Catholic seeking out the leader of ISIS and killing him would be committing murder. Because the man has no lawful or justified reason for going out of his way to kill a man. The whole subject has been brought up under the premise suggested in the Question, and at the mention of the term in conjunction with the Fifth Commandment, many are ready to jump without considering the Asker's specified scenario.

Comment: It just seems like half your answer is unnecessary (and not necessarily good exegesis) to the point you've affirmed in a comment. The answer would be just as good without the additional edit. Nobody argues that there aren't cases of killing that are justified. The question (the OP is asking) is, _is this instance justified?_